# Flask 0.11 CLI dev server -- specify host?

Tags: flask

With Flask 0.11 it is highly recommend to run the dev server from the command line, however, I cannot figure out how to change the host.  I need to access this externally so previously I used app.run(host="0.0.0.0") which worked fine, but I can't find the equivalent for running this from the command line.  I tried setting app.config["SERVER_NAME"] = "0.0.0.0" but the dev server isn't picking this up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run with `--host` option

```
flask run --host='0.0.0.0'
```

To see all available options

```
flask run --help
```

Comment: Is this possible with `python -m flask`? Running just flask fails to find my module but running python works.

Comment: Yes, if you don’t want to install Flask or you have a special use-case you can also use `python -m flask` to accomplish exactly the same: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/cli/#basic-usage

Comment: Great, `python -m flask run --host='0.0.0.0'` worked perfectly.